# jquery .load() is not loading the next external file in a created div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-load

so, I'm trying to implement a loading function that will carry out the jquery code from my first page of the application to include the pages loaded on that page ..
i.e. page1.html has a an empty div with id="content" that I want it populated with another external page in my root folder.. i tried the following ...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  
$('input').click(function() {  
$.ajax({
  url: "./page2.html",
  type: "GET"
  }).done(function(response, status, xhr) {
  $("#div1").html(response);
  alert(status + " : " + xhr) 
  }); 
 }); 
});
```

And HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <title>my Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript/jquery.mobile-1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
  <script src="javascript/jquery.mobile-1.3.1/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/jquery.mobile-1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
  <script src="my.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
     <!-- Question1 -->
    <div id="question1" data-role="page" class="questionContainer radius" data-theme="b">
      <div id="hbox" data-theme="b" data-role="header">
          <a id="bb1" class="back_button" data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="index.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">
                  Back
               </a>
              <a id="hb1" data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="app-help.html" data-icon="info"
          data-iconpos="right" class="ui-btn-right">
               Help
           </a>
         <h3 id="q1">
               Question 1
         </h3>
       </div>
       <div class="question"><h3>Q1:is this even right?</h3></div>
          <h3 id="c1" style="border:solid;">
              What Ever is the Question!
           </h3>
            <div id="rb1" data-role="fieldcontain" class="answers">
               <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
                   <legend>
                       Choose:
                   </legend>
                   <ul>
                     <li><input id="q1-a" class="a1" name="Radio Buttons" value="radio1" type="radio"/> 
                     <label for="q1-a">
                       Yes.
                      </label></li>
                     <li><input id="q1-b" class="b1" name="Radio Buttons" value="radio2" type="radio"/>
                <label for="q1-b">
                  No.
                </label></li>
              </ul>
          </fieldset>
      </div>
    <div class="btnContainer">
            <div id="next1">
                <input id="next1" class="next" type="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" value="Next" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right"/>
            </div>
        </div>
 <div id="fbox" data-theme="b" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <span class="ui-title">
         </span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div1"></div>

  </body>
 </html>
```

okay... UPDATE, I tried numerous answers from around the web but nothing have managed to show the second page like i wanted in the div..it is GETting it, but not displaying it .. and also i removed a chunk of jQuery which was suppose to capture the user's results and calculate the score at the end ..but for some reason that chunk of code was causing the page not to get anything, however, when i removed the code..page one was displaying again when i clicked on the next button .. but with mixed up formatting...again firebug is showing me that i'm getting the second page..but displaying page one.. help is appreciated :)
 I was advised by someone that it maybe a jQuery or CSS that is interfering with my ajax.. I mean..I don't know what to do ..... anyhow ..thank you very much for the previous help..!

M

Comment: @MohammadAdil What do you mean? He want's to change the element present in the loaded HTML and not changing the file itself.

Comment: hmm .. i missed that part

Comment: thank you for your very fast reply ! ...I was wondering if you can point me to something about that ? that would be really helpful :) thank you again

Comment: oh O_O yes i forgot to mention that..sorry..and am a she :P

Comment: Just so you know, you can specify the element to load in the load function. $('#content').load('page2.html #Page2ElementId');

Comment: Try removing `$('this').trigger('create')`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?  It seems like you're do a lot of extra stuff, when all you want to do is load the content into your div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  // load document 
    $.ajax({
      url: "page2.html",
      context: document.body
    }).done(function(response, status, xhr) {
      $("#content").html(response);
      alert(status + " : " + xhr) //alert me with the server response, status
    }); 
});
</script>
```

If you really do need this to happen on a click event, then move it inside the click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  // load document 
 $('.next').click(function() {  //use the class of "next" when clicked and ...
    $.ajax({
      url: "page2.html",
      context: document.body
    }).done(function(response, status, xhr) {
      $("#content").html(response);
      alert(status + " : " + xhr) //alert me with the server response, status
    }); 
  }); 
 });
});
```

Comment: ok...I tried this code...it's working to some extent as it's showing me the div i created for the next page rather than the page itself ...am not sure what to do..but thank you !!! this is really helpful

Comment: btw, it's giving the alert of a successful status i.e. success: object Object ...I'm even more confused..

Comment: okay, I played around with ALOT..and still no fully working result .. as it is taking the text from the 2nd page and displaying it on the 1st page..while loading the second page ..nothing happens ...although I'm sure that it is GETting something ..checked it with firebug ..and using a local host ..so..if you - or anyone - kindly can show me how to fix this ..am willing to upload the whole thing if it takes.. thank you, M

Answer (score 0):

What I can spot is that you are trying to call create on the element itself.

When you call `$('this')`($(this) is used to referring to the "current element") you should instead refer to the parent element when you call `.trigger('create');` to create the new div. The parent element in this case seems to be `$('.next')`.

Your code would be:

```
$('.next').click(function() { 
  var amaparent = $(this);
  $("#content").load("page2.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
   amaparent.trigger('create');
  }); 
 });
```